# How to handle applying for multiple jobs at once (with different companies)

Tags: professionalism, job-search

I have been applying for jobs for the summer and after a long period of inactivity many are calling me back all at once. It's slightly stressful and I'm worried I will take a job only to get an offer from a one I would have preferred. Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I don't want to become overly sceptical just because I'm doing multiple interviews with different companies in a week: for example when I was called to schedule an interview two different people called me, normally I would not think much of this but I find presently I'm becoming hyper vigilant and take this as a sign they are disorganized.

Also I'm concerned that at time I may say I'm available for an interview may be taken up by another company before the first gets back. For example if I say I am available 9-5 with company Apples and tell the same to company Oranges, what if they pick overlapping times?

Comment: There are many topics about juggling job offers, do any of those fail to address your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a calendar to schedule your available time. When anyone calls to ask you if you are available, check it. If you make the appointment, mark the calendar as unavailable. Then when the next person calls asking if you are available, the answer is "No. However I have time available at *some other time frame*."

Don't schedule interviews close to each other. You will need time to go from one to another, the first one will run longer than expected, there will be a wreck between locations, or something else.

You are the keeper of your own schedule. These companies are coming to you. They expect that you will be able to track your own time.

Good luck on your search!